# Older road bike: squeaky crank?

Tags: road-bike, crankset

I have an old Free Spirit road bike. It's in good shape and runs fine, but I started noticing that when I'm going uphill or pedaling in a high gear there is a squeaky sound coming from what seems to be the crank.

Any tips on fixing it or could it be another issue altogether?

Comment: Definitely check (or have your LBS check) that the crank fixing bolts are tight.  Also you may want to have your LBS check the crank cups.

Comment: It's devilishly difficult sometimes to pinpoint the position of a noise whilst you are riding. And even harder to replicate the noises when you are not riding. A friend cycling next to and around you can help located the source of said noises.

Comment: A photo of your bottom bracket and cranks would help. It'd make a big difference if you had cottered cranks or a one piece crank, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed my crank making a noise when I would crank hard, and it ended up being the pedal. It was the cheap plastic pedals that came with the bike (before I switched to clipless), and the pedal itself was starting to break. It would bend when I was cranking hard, and it finally broke on me (thankfully, just down the street from my house).

So, I would check the pedal, and check the bolts for the whole area to make sure everything's tightened down properly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the pedals. They're stock so probably pretty cheap plastic as well.

Comment: Yep, I've had several problems with pedals as well, and not just "cheap" ones (though not top-of-the-line either).

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and after checking bottom bracket, pedals, and chainrings, spraying some lubricant into the rear hub did the trick.  I did not even remove the wheel; just sprayed into the hub.  Good luck!

Comment: Its probably a temp fix - you'd benefit from a complete teardown and new bearings in the rear wheel.

Comment: Bearings are new;  several muddy rides gunked it up.